# How to get User Location using GPS signal's From Android App to showed in Web Application

Tags: android, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I developed Web Application and small Android Application(for getting GPS signal's). I need to show user tracking (Not Live tracking) in google maps (Just click on button in web Application and to show his marker in Map). I showed google maps in web Application. But How can I get user Latitude and Longitude values from the App to web Application When Admin click on track button in web Application. In Web Application side, I used Spring frame work. I don't know How can I implement.Please help me.

Comment: I might not be understanding you correctly, but you can just get the lat long straight from the browser. You don't need an app to do that. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: I am giving app to user for getting gps signals because admin to show the user track(Not live tracking) in google maps in web application. But How can I get user GPS signals from app to the Web application.!!!!!!!!!!1